# pass reference to another function in python for a recursive function to print series of numbers within limits

Tags: python, function, recursion, reference

Python function names **'series'** to input two numbers from user and pass those numbers to a recursive function named **'display_series’** which should display all the integers between the given numbers. The ‘display_series’ function must be a recursive function. Note that the first given number can be greater than second number or it can be less than second number (or even both numbers can be equal), in all cases series should be printed.

```
def series():
    a = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    b = int(input("Enter second number: "))

def display_series(i):
    i==b
    if(a>b):
        return a.append(a-1)
    elif (a<b):
        return a.append(a+1)
    else:
        print ("Nothing")
```

i have no idea to pass values in python ... this is something not working but i was thinking of such logic can be applied your suggestion matters alot :)

Comment: Can you clarify "between the given numbers".  For instance If a = 0, b = 3 should output be the numbers `1, 2` (i.e. just the numbers in between the two numbers)?

Comment: if a=3, b=0 output should be like 0,1,2,3 and if a=0,b=3 output should be the same 0,1,2,3 i hope you can help @DarrylG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
def series():
    a = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    b = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    
    display_series(a, b)

def display_series(a, b):
  " Recursive print integers in the interval [a, b] inclusive "

  if a > b:
    # Ensure a is always the lower number
    a, b = b, a

  # print lower number
  print(a)

  if a == b:
    # Done
    return
  else:
    # Recursive call
    display_series(a+1, b)
```

**Test 1**

```
series()
```

*Output*

```
Enter first number: 0
Enter second number: 3
0
1
2
3
```

**Test 2**

```
series()
```

*Output*

```
Enter first number: 3
Enter second number: 0
0
1
2
3
```